# Reading JSON in Google Sheets with Google Script

Tags: javascript, json, google-sheets-api

I am currently pulling data from an external API to Google Sheets and wanted to get a certain part of the data to show from the JSON.  The only part that should be added to the cell is `$440.00` but currently it shows `{"data":[{"cost":"$440.00"}],"success":true,"totalNumRows":1}`.  Is there a way to just pull that?

```
// Add menu to run program
function onOpen() {
var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
ui.createMenu('Get Crobo Cost')
    .addItem('Display daily cost', 'callCrobo')
    .addToUi();
}


// Function to call Crobo
function callCrobo() {
// Call Crobo daily spend
var apiKey = '****omitted****'

var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch("http://cis.crobo.com/stats/stats.json?api_key=" + apiKey + "&start_date=2018-03-12&end_date=2018-03-12&field[]=Stat.revenue")
Logger.log(response.getContentText());

// Parse to JSON reply
var json = response.getContentText();
var obj = JSON.parse(json);

Logger.log(obj.data);

//Gets hold of ActiveSheet in current workbook
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();

// Set value in cell A1
sheet.getRange(sheet.getLastRow() + 1,1).setValue([response]);
}
```

The logger's current output is:

```
[18-03-13 17:22:02:377 EDT] {"data":
[{"cost":"$440.00"}],"success":true,"totalNumRows":1}
[18-03-13 17:22:02:378 EDT] undefined
```

Thank you

Comment: Cost is wrapped in an object in an array.  Try this:

obj.data[0].cost

Comment: wow. thanks. that was pretty simple.

Comment: No problem.  It can get a little tricky when objects are nested in that fashion.  You just have to trace it up or down carefully.  Good luck. :)